# Where is "click link on webpage" Action in the new version of Power Automate

Tags: power-automate

I'm looking for information to show me how I can use Power Automate to download data from a webpage by clicking on a 'click link to download' button.

I'm very new to Power Automate and I've seen some YouTube videos showing how to use Power Automate to do exactly what I need. However they are all showing the older version of Power Automate and I need to do the same thing but using the newest version.
There's nothing available showing how to do it.
Can anyone help please?

This is what they are using in the old version.
[image]

This is as far as I've got on the new version. Which only takes me to the webpage.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing Power Automate Desktop flows (RPA) with Power Automate cloud flows. These are two different type of flows.

Make sure you create a Desktop flow.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/desktop-flows/create-flow

This should start the Power Automate Desktop client which still has the [Click link on a web page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/power-automate/desktop-flows/actions-reference/webautomation#clickbase) action. (I checked the 2.21 version, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/released-versions/power-automate-desktop/2206.1).